# Advice on building an aquarium stand

Tags: structural-engineering, structural-analysis, welding

I'm building a kitchen/bar in my unused basement area, and want to incorporate my 180 gallon saltwater aquarium into the design.

Before I decide on a design, I wanted to ask for advice/opinions on viability of this design.

I have never welded, and have other metal-working projects I want to take on, so before I purchase equipment, I wanted to get advice on this project as well.  Moving forward, I'd like to work with aluminum so part of my question is what materials can/should I use if this design is sound.

**Thing it needs to hold:**

- This will weigh roughly 2000lbs when filled.

[image]

**Design:**

- Is this design strong enough to hold the weight of tank?

  - Can this design be simplified?
- What materials should I use?

[image]

**Intended Usage:**

[image]

- The usage is to be mounted above a countertop in the kitchen area
- Safety is obviously a concern, this will be suspended above a work space. I want to know that both the inhabitants of the tank, and the inhabitants of the house are safe.
- This can be mounted directly into the basement walls and floor, both of which are concrete.

Comment: You will not be able to weld aluminum without training and special equipment, not the garden variety welding equipment used for steel. I suggest wood. I have built a cantilever stand for 40 gal, with wood, no problem.,

Comment: @blacksmith37 I haven't ruled out wood entirely, but I haven't been able to figure out to calculate the sag to feel confident.

Comment: What are the dimensions of the aquarium ? The length of the cantilever-like shelf will strongly affect strain/sag. Another consideration with aluminum is the traditional filler metals are low strength - will not harden.

Comment: The aquarium is 6' long, and 2' tall, and 2' deep.

Answer (score 1):

No this will not work unless supported like truss bridge.

[image]

Even this [500 lb shelf](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07YM8RLW8) would collapse  [image]